# EF Many-Many Relation Circular Loading

Tags: entity-framework

Lets say I have EntityA that have  multiple of EntityB and EntityB can have multiple of EntityA. For simplicity:

```
class Student
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Teacher> Teachers{get;set;}
}

class Teacher
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Student> Students{get;set;}
}
```

I do mapping like this:

```
HasMany(x => x.Teachers)
.WithMany(x => x.Students)
.Map(x => 
{
    x.MapLeftKey("StudentId");
    x.MapRightKey("TeacherId");
    x.ToTable("StudentTeacher");
});
```

Lazy loading is turned of.

Then I want to load Student including Teachers (meaning only Name of Teacher) but not other Students and then Teachers curculary. I tried something like this:

```
var student = _context.Students.Where(x => x.Name == studentName)
 .Include(x=>x.Teachers)
 .SingleOrDefault();
```

But I really get a objects. I only want to load the first level.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behavior even though when debugging it seems like you are loading the entire object graph, EF is only populating children entities with the initial entity.

Let's say you have this data:

Tables:

Students

```
1 | Student1
2 | Student2
```

Teachers

```
1 | Teacher1
2 | Teacher2
```

StudentTeacher

```
1 | 1
1 | 2
2 | 1
2 | 2
```

EF query

```
var student = _context.Students.Where(x => x.Name == "Student1")
 .Include(x=>x.Teachers)
 .SingleOrDefault();
```

gives you:

```
student.Teachers  = ("Teacher1", "Teacher2")

student.Teachers[1].Students = ("Student1")
student.Teachers[2].Students = ("Student1")
```

You can see how the last 2 lines only bring back `"Student1"` even though each teacher has `{"Student1", "Student2"}` attached to them.

Comment: Well. This is what I expect, but that is not really what I get. My problem is that I get also full "Student" objects. I do not really have "students" and "teachers", I only put this as a simple example.

Comment: It seems that you are right. What I was experiancing is VS Debugger feature.

Comment: Let me test a little bit more.

Comment: what I meant is, if you look at my example, even though the object graph is infinite, the data is "incorrect", and only that data that was loaded in the first level is being display in the third level.

Comment: Yes, I do know what you mean. My implementation is in the same way. Initially I saw problem with serialization when I access my system through Web API. Than I configure JSON serializer ignore reference loop handling, that it worked but with partially complete graph of object, without duplicates, since JSON serializer handles this. Than I found out lazy loading is on (I was assuming it was not :-) ). I turned it off, start to debug, and in debugger I saw "complete graph" of object loaded, but I did not assume that this was feature of debugger.

Comment: So, when I access my system again through Web API, now I have expected behavior. To make long story short, my problem was lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I saw problem with serialization when I access my system through Web API. Than I configure JSON serializer ignore reference loop handling, that it worked but with partially complete graph of object, without duplicates, since JSON serializer handles this. Than I found out lazy loading is on (I was assuming it was not :-) ). I turned it off, start to debug, and in debugger I saw "complete graph" of object loaded, but I did not assume that this was feature of debugger.

So, when I access my system again through Web API, now I have expected behavior. To make long story short, my problem was **lazy loading**